# want to show file path after selecting file for upload in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, file-upload, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.2

I am creating a `formpanel` in sencha touch and i have a field where there is a file upload option and to upload a file i am using one extension [source](https://github.com/kostysh/File-uploading-component-for-Sencha-Touch)

i have two issues

> 1) I don't know how to show the file path in a `textfield` as this
>   extension has only upload    button.
>
> 2) When i align `textfield` with `fileupload` i am not getting
>   following output which is getting squeezed rather then stretch.

[image]

here is the code ,i have tried `fullscreen:true` but the output is same

```
{

    layout: 'hbox',
    items:[{
            xtype:'textfield',
            label:'File Upload',

        },{

            xtype: 'fileupload',
            name: 'nofile',
            label: 'File Upload:'

        }]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the same plugin, faced same problem to get the uploaded file.

Now changed to another plugin in this one is very simple and you will the get uploaded file url, and also you can preview the uploaded file.

http://moduscreate.com/device-camera-access-with-sencha-touch/

Comment: but what should i download for sencha touch from this as there are plenty of folders at github

Comment: download the mobile folder, there you will find example app